# Modify the dates within the string using Python

Tags: python, string

The input string is something as below:
"AADFDMNB12144.V12-JAN-23FFFFFSWSWS.XCX15-FEB-22JHJH1111LOP4-JAN-22KKKKKK"

This string contains 3 date values. Likewise there will be more. Need to develop a logic which identifies the data present anywhere within the string in the format DD-MMM-YY and convert it back to YY-MM-DD.

input --> "AADFDMNB12144.V**12-JAN-23**FFFFFSWSWS.XCX**15-FEB-22**JHJH1111LOP**4-JAN-22**KKKKKK"

output --> "AADFDMNB12144.V**23-01-12**FFFFFSWSWS.XCX**22-02-15**JHJH1111LOP**22-01-4**KKKKKK"

I am currently writing the logic to search for each month name like "-JAN-", "-FEB-", ...... and so on. Then looping the individual times to capture the month counter. Then extract the length of the date value by calculating the index of the "-MonthName-", then taking the length of 2 before and 2 after to get the date value. Post getting the date value breaking the value into 3 parts using array and then swapping the date value with year value while keeping the month value in between.
The logic is still not complete.

The issue is whatever logic am writing is traversing the code once and I am stuck at this point. Also, further to the solution there must exist a better approach.

Approaching to this scenario as below:

```
    cellvalue = 'AADFDMNB12144.V**12-JAN-23**FFFFFSW-SWS.XCX**15-FEB-22**JHJH1111LOP**4-JAN-22**KKKKKK'
    count=int(cellvalue.count('-'))
    print('No. of hyphen...',count)
    jancounter=0
    febcounter=0
    if count > 0:
        print('There are no dates')
    else:
        for x in range (0,count):
            if '-JAN' in cellvalue:
                jancounter = jancounter + 1
            if '-FEB-' in cellvalue:
                febcounter = febcounter + 1
            ::::::: so on for all the months ::::::::

    print(jancounter)
    print(febcounter)
```

Output:
> No. of hyphen...7
> There are no dates

Basically the logic am trying to write is not going correct in the first step as it is not entering the else part at all. Also, am looking for a better way to acheieve this situation.

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 1):

Use a regex with [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) and [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) functions to parse and change the format:

```
import re
from datetime import datetime
from calendar import month_abbr

cellvalue = "AADFDMNB12144.V12-JAN-23FFFFFSWSWS.XCX15-FEB-22JHJH1111LOP4-JAN-22KKKKKK"

pattern = r'(0?[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])-('+'|'.join(m.upper() for m in month_abbr[1:])+r')-\d{2}'
# '(0[1-9]|[12]\\d|3[01])-(JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC)-\\d{2}'

out = re.sub(pattern, lambda m: datetime.strptime(m.group(), '%d-%b-%y').strftime('%y-%m-%-d'), cellvalue)
```

Output: `'AADFDMNB12144.V23-01-12FFFFFSWSWS.XCX22-02-15JHJH1111LOP22-01-4KKKKKK'`

Because the regex won't prevent invalid dates (e.g. 31-FEB-23), you can also use a function to validate them:

```
def change_format(m, in_fmt='%d-%b-%y', out_fmt='%y-%m-%-d'):
    try:
        datetime.strptime(m.group(), in_fmt).strftime(out_fmt)
    except ValueError:
        return m.group()
        
out = re.sub(pattern, change_format, cellvalue)
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/s2nkJY/1)

Comment: In order to get exactly what OP requires as output the format specifier '%y-%m-%d' should be '%y-%m-%-d'

Comment: @DarkKnight you're right, I missed this detail, thanks!

Comment: Getting error as :
ValueError: Invalid format string
Pls help.

Comment: @NehaM please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76763594/edit) your question with the exact command that you used and the exact error message. Can you reproduce my code with the example?

Comment: What is the type of `cellvalue`?

Comment: Its actually coming from each cell within the specific excel file

Comment: OK, but is it a string? What I gave you is a way to change **one string**, so you have to ensure `cellvalue` is a string. You haven't answered all my questions. Have you tested my code by copy/pasting all and running?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using regular expressions, [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) specifically. This would avoid repetition:

```
import re

cellvalue = 'AADFDMNB12144.V**12-JAN-23**FFFFFSW-SWS.XCX**15-FEB-22**JHJH1111LOP**4-JAN-22**KKKKKK'
months = ['JAN', 'FEB'] # fill missing months
counter = dict()
for m in months:
    counter[m] = len(re.findall(rf'-{m}-', cellvalue, re.IGNORECASE))
print(counter)
```

Output:

```
{'JAN': 2, 'FEB': 1}
```

Comment: This step is giving output as mentioned. 
Is there a way to capture and reference the indexes for each month. I need these value to sum up first and then iterate for the each time for the mentioned month.

Comment: What do you mean with indexes? My answer covers your code attempt (counting occurences for each month) but I overlooked your broader goal which seems achieved by @mozway's answer. I don't really get what you're after tbh

Answer (score 0):

Could achieve the solution by using following functions:

1. Index to find the occurrences of the month name
2. finding the exact position
3. converting the month to equivalent number
4. Rearranging the values.